# Propagation delay and arrival time

Tags: homework, propagation

I am trying to determine the arrival of signals from 3 separate beacons to point x. I have found the distances from x to each beacon as well the propagating wave speed but I do not know how to determine the arrival time. I calculated the propagation delay, but I am unsure if this would be the answer. These are radio beacons. It is for a application and assignment.

Comment: Remember, we don't know who you are or what you are doing. We only know what you wrote in your question. So please edit the question and try to provide some basic information about what you are doing. First, are these laser signals, or radio beacons or acoustic beacons or what? Second, why are you trying to calculate the arrival time? Did someone tell you that you need to do that, or are you going to use the information for some purpose? What purpose? If I had to guess, I would say this sounds like a positioning application, but that is just a guess.

Comment: okay I will do that

Comment: I think you can consider the arrival time of the earliest signal to be time t=0, and all other times are after t=0. But ideally you would ask the professor for clarification. It should not be an important detail. The main thing is calculating the propagation time for each signal, as you have done.